# Translating MySQL NOT IN to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've recently started using MongoDB, and while translating queries, I've stumbled upon a problem when trying to translate MySQL NOT IN query.

What I'm trying to do is find ids that are not present in another collection. I need a way to return how many of these ids there are and then a list of these ids.

In MySQL, these ids are in a table called `songs` and are named `spotify_id`. I am checking against a table named `artists` where the ids are called `track_id`.

MySQL Query:

```sql
SELECT spotify_id FROM songs WHERE spotify_id NOT IN (SELECT artists.track_id FROM artists)
```

My current code using MongoDB:

```py
track_ids = artists.find({}, {'track_id': 1})
track_ids_list = [d.get('track_id') for d in track_ids]

# Getting amount of ids not present in artists
tracks_num = songs.count_documents({'spotify_id': {'$nin': track_ids_list}})

# Getting tracks not present in artists
tracks = songs.find({'spotify_id': {'$nin': track_ids_list}})
```

The MongoDB query seems to return a positive number of documents, even when all of the ids should be present in both collections. The MySQL query works perfectly on the same database.

Is there a better way to perform a NOT IN query in MongoDB?

Thank you!

Comment: `songs`  and  `artists` are different tables in MySQL, which is fine since you are normalizing your data. Mongodb is a NOSQL db, so modify your schema to incorporate the song and artists details in the same collection for better results

Comment: As in include information about the artists within the songs document?

Comment: Yes that would be a better approach, even though the artists information is repeated in multiple songs, the retrieval of data is faster, since all the information is available in a single document.

Comment: Makes sense, I suppose I have to change my way of thinking about databases.
Thank you for your help!